# Issue with select where in openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, openquery

I have an openquery that I using to hit an Oracle DB with from SQL server. The query runs without error but does not return any results. If I take out the sub select and change it to where pid = and input any of the ids on the list I get results.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM openquery(DBtest04, 
'SELECT * FROM DBUSER.PLOG where 
pid in (''select pid from dbtest.dbo.gsy 
'') and timeofevent > to_date(''2015-01-01 12:00'',''yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi'')  ')
```

If I run this query I get 239 rows returned:

```
    'SELECT * FROM DBUSER.PLOG where 
    pid = 990066657 and timeofevent > to_date(''2015-10-25 12:00'',''yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi'')  ')
```

Comment: First, are you sure the query runs without errors (as opposed to "the errors were handled, by sending them to NULL")? It turns out a lot of lazy programmers do just that. Then, are you able to run the query directly in the target database to see if it returns any results?

Comment: Try doing just a `SELECT * FROM DBUSER.PLOG` in the open query without the complicated Where clause to see if you get results

Comment: If I do the following query I get 239 rows retruned:
        'SELECT * FROM DBUSER.PLOG where 
 pid = 990066657 and timeofevent > to_date(''2015-10-25          12:00'',''yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi'')  ')